# Show/hide span id on select selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show checkbox when i select `ms` from the select option value, checkbox is specified in span's id `boxcheck`. If other then show radio button with span id `radiocheck`

This is what I am trying which is not working:

```js
$('#Typeselect').change(function() {
  var value = this.value;

  if (selectedValue === 'ms') {
    $('#radiocheck').show();
    $('#boxcheck').hide();
  } else {
    $('#radiocheck').hide();
    $('#boxcheck').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 operations">
  <span style="display:none" id="boxcheck">
    <input type="checkbox" name="correct['+val+questions+'][]"> Correct
  </span>
  <span id="radiocheck" style="display:none">
    <input type="radio" name="correct['+val+questions+'][]"> Correct
  </span>
</div>
<select class="form-control" id="Typeselect" name="question_type[]" Required>
  <option value="txt">Text</option>
  <option value="ms">Color text</option>
  <option value="mm">Rainbow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have a typo. You set `value`, but use `selectedValue` in your `if` statement. First rule of debugging JS; check the console. Fix the typo and the code works fine.

Comment: Not working.. I have fixed the typo.

Comment: Trust me, it does: https://jsfiddle.net/5kje0v1r/

Comment: Change `selectedValue` to `value`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan should get the credit.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat thanks, but no credit required. In theory questions where the fault is just a typo should just be closed, although this one now has too many answers to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/q4gq95gf/1/)

As mentioned in comment above, it meant to change Variable name from *value* to **selectedValue**.

Try the below solution:

```js
$('#Typeselect').change(function() {
  var selectedValue = this.value;

  if (selectedValue === 'ms') {
    $('#radiocheck').show();
    $('#boxcheck').hide();
  } else {
    $('#radiocheck').hide();
    $('#boxcheck').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 operations">
  <span style="display:none" id="boxcheck">
    <input type="checkbox" name="correct['+val+questions+'][]"> Correct
  </span>
  <span id="radiocheck" style="display:none">
    <input type="radio" name="correct['+val+questions+'][]"> Correct
  </span>
</div>
<select class="form-control" id="Typeselect" name="question_type[]" Required>
  <option value="txt">Text</option>
  <option value="ms">Color text</option>
  <option value="mm">Rainbow</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working now

```js
$('#Typeselect').change(function() {
  var value = this.value;

  if (value === 'ms') {
    $('#radiocheck').show();
    $('#boxcheck').hide();
  } else {
    $('#radiocheck').hide();
    $('#boxcheck').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 operations">
  <span style="display:none" id="boxcheck">
    <input type="checkbox" name="correct['+val+questions+'][]"> Correct
  </span>
  <span id="radiocheck" style="display:none">
    <input type="radio" name="correct['+val+questions+'][]"> Correct
  </span>
</div>
<select class="form-control" id="Typeselect" name="question_type[]" Required>
  <option value="txt">Text</option>
  <option value="ms">Color text</option>
  <option value="mm">Rainbow</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
  $('#Typeselect').change(function() {

  //you had a typo here...
  var selectedValue = this.value;

  if (selectedValue === 'ms') {
    $('#radiocheck').show();
    $('#boxcheck').hide();
  } else {
    $('#radiocheck').hide();
    $('#boxcheck').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use need to use `value` in if condition

```js
$('#Typeselect').change(function() {
  var value  = this.value;

  if (value  === 'ms') {
    $('#radiocheck').show();
    $('#boxcheck').hide();
  } else {
    $('#radiocheck').hide();
    $('#boxcheck').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 operations">
  <span style="display:none" id="boxcheck">
    <input type="checkbox" name="correct['+val+questions+'][]"> Correct
  </span>
  <span id="radiocheck" style="display:none">
    <input type="radio" name="correct['+val+questions+'][]"> Correct
  </span>
</div>
<select class="form-control" id="Typeselect" name="question_type[]" Required>
  <option value="txt">Text</option>
  <option value="ms">Color text</option>
  <option value="mm">Rainbow</option>
</select>
```